# Add the content of input box to the end of a url

Tags: html, forms

So for example a user would type "hasibasi" into an input box, press submit and they would be taken to:

http://google.com/hasibasi

Comment: it totally depend on your technology or tools, you can search or check tutorials of that on youtube. it's really a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically change the form action with JavaScript like so:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("i");
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
function go(){
  form.action=form.action+input.value;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/" method="POST">
  <input id="i" required>
  <button onclick="go()">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how can i use it?

Comment: @hasibasi Ask a different question if you don't know how to use HTML